# StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml() problem in unescaping HTML entities for Android

Tags: html, android, entity, stringescapeutils, lang

This is what I'm doing:

```
public static String htmlToText(String inString)
{
String noentity=StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(inString);
return noentity;
}
```

This is where I'm invoking it:

```
String html = "<html><body>string 1<br />&#8212;<p>string 2</p></body></html>";
    String nohtml = Utility.htmlToText(html);
    Log.i("NON HTML STRING:",nohtml);
```

And this is the output in the log:

```
10-13 12:38:12.121: INFO/NON HTML STRING:(300): <html><body>string 1<br />â<p>string 2</p></body></html>
```

According to the reference at http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html `&#8212;` should be replaced by a "—" (which is the output I expect) and not a "â" (which is not what I want).

At first I was using JSoup and the same thing was happening. Thinking it to be a bug, I switched to org.apache.commons.lang and the same thing is happening.

Anyone else know what's going on here? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.java.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.....

It was a problem with the output in Logcat.

Putting a breakpoint showed me the actual output which was correct.

This is the second time the Logcat tool has thrown me off course....